# How to get auto-increment PK on a multi-row insert in MySql

Tags: mysql

I need to get back a list of "affected" ids when inserting multiple rows at once. Some rows might already be there, resulting in an update instead.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `update_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO users (id, email, is_active)
VALUES (NULL, "joe@mail.org", true),
       (NULL, "jack@mail.org", false),
       (NULL, "dave@mail.org", true)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
       is_active = VALUES(is_active)
```

There is a UNIQUE constraint on `email`.

From what I gathered, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` would only give me first generated id of the batch. But I wouldn't know how many inserts/updates really took place.

The only way I could come up with is to follow with a second SELECT statement:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE email IN ("joe@mail.org", "jack@mail.org", "dave@mail.org")
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: You can read the affected_rows to get the number of inserted rows. The generated keys are in sequence with no gaps according to the increment step value

Comment: Show DDL for `users`. What constraint must cause ODKU?

Comment: Do you have modified timestamp that you can use? Otherwise the best way is to have a column where you can insert a batch id and then query the table afterwards on that batch id

Comment: @Akina sorry forgot to explain that, a UNIQUE constraint, I updated the `name` field to be `email` so it clearer that is is unique.

Comment: If so your second SELECT query is a solution. The only solution (on some DBMSs there exists OUTPUT/RETURNING clause but MySQL does not support it).

Comment: @Psi affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values. So it is inconclusive really for a batch insert.

Comment: @SteveMapes I like the batch id idea. As for timestamp, I have one that is in the DDL, I would need to generate and insert it myself instead if I want to use it in a subsequent query, right?

Comment: @AhmadAbdelghany Yes that is correct you will need to generate it before running the query